# Oracle 11g - Fast Refresh on Materialized View with JOIN

Tags: oracle11g, inner-join, materialized-views

**EDIT: I solved my problem changing JOINs to non-ANSI format... but I still wish to know how to make FAST REFRESH work with Materialized Views built on queries containing JOINs, if possible.**

on Oracle 11g it seems that I cannot FAST REFRESH materialized views. To perform some tests I've created the following two tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_1
(n   NUMBER NOT NULL,
 v   VARCHAR2 (1),
 d   DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX t_1_pk ON test_1 (n);

ALTER TABLE test_1 ADD (
  CONSTRAINT t_1_pk
  PRIMARY KEY (n)
  USING INDEX t_1_pk
  ENABLE VALIDATE);

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON test_1 WITH ROWID, PRIMARY KEY;
```

and

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_2
(n    NUMBER NOT NULL,
 n1   NUMBER,
 v    VARCHAR2 (1),
 d    DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX t_2_pk ON test_2 (n);

ALTER TABLE test_2 ADD (
  CONSTRAINT t_2_pk
  PRIMARY KEY (n)
  USING INDEX t_2_pk
  ENABLE VALIDATE,
  CONSTRAINT t_2_fk
  FOREIGN KEY (n1)
  REFERENCING test_1 (n));

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON test_2 WITH ROWID, PRIMARY KEY;
```

each filled with random data.
Then I tried to create a simple Materialized View:

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test_mv
   BUILD IMMEDIATE
   REFRESH FAST ON DEMAND AS
   SELECT t1.ROWID rid1,
          t2.ROWID rid2,
          t1.n n1,
          t1.v v1,
          t2.n n2,
          t2.v v2
     FROM test_1 t1 JOIN test_2 t2 ON t1.n = t2.n1;
```

but I got the following error:

```sql
ORA-12015: cannot create a fast refresh materialized view from a complex query
```

Removing the JOIN (i.e. selecting only from one base table) I'm able to build the MView. I tried to search for some system parameter to check, but it seems only a problem of static query. The strange thing is that my query does not contain any invalid expression (I've checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49578932/materialized-view-in-oracle-with-fast-refresh-instead-of-complete-dosnt-work), [this article](http://www.dba-oracle.com/art_9i_mv.htm) and in many other documentation sites and posts). Also, I have worked for a long time with Oracle 12c and I have never had difficulty in creating materialized views.

Comment: You should read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505020/oracle-how-to-create-a-materialized-view-with-fast-refresh-and-joins also.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai: I've done both steps suggested in the accepted answer already (base tables' ROWIDs included in SELECT clause, materialized view logs created with WITH ROWID clause). But the accepted answer uses non-ANSI joins in the materialized view query, not standard JOIN as mentioned in the question. I came to the same conclusion at the end, read my EDIT in the question.